# Referencing multiple columns and rows to calculate new value in a new column

Tags: r, data-manipulation, data-wrangling

Here is my data.frame {sf}. I converted this to longform, so the UID represents the polygon. In each UID there is anywhere from 0 to 3 species present. Sum percent for each UID will be 100 or 0.

| UID | ORDER | SPECIES | PERCENT | geometry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A | 80 | blahblah |
| 1 | 2 | BL | 15 | blahblah |
| 1 | 3 | P | 5 | blahblah |
| 2 | 1 | S | 75 | blahblah |
| 2 | 2 | E | 25 | blahblah |
| 2 | 3 | *na* | 0 | blahblah |
| 3 | 1 | PA | 61 | blahblah |
| 3 | 2 | AT | 39 | blahblah |
| 3 | 3 | *na* | 0 | blahblah |
| 4 | 1 | *na* | 0 | blahblah |
| 4 | 2 | *na* | 0 | blahblah |
| 4 | 3 | *na* | 0 | blahblah |

I want to create a new entry in a new column "ZONE" with these values:

- If each unique UID does not contain A or AT for species, then enter "Misc." into ZONE.
- If all species values for a unique UID is *na*, then enter *na* into Zone.
- If a UID contains A or AT and the percent in the next cell of A or AT is >= 80, then enter "For". If <80 enter "Gra"

This was my attempt:

```
list < - c("A", "AT")
data.frame$ZONE <- (data.frame$SPECIES %in% list)
data.frame$ZONE[data.frame$ZONE == TRUE] <- "For"
data.frame$ZONE[is.na(data.frame$SPECIES)] <- NA
data.frame$ZONE[data.frame$ZONE == FALSE] <- "Misc."
```

This resulted in every row being treated as an individual instead of being grouped by IUD. Also, I completely disregarded the >=80 or <.

I want it to look like this:

| UID | ORDER | SPECIES | PERCENT | ZONE | geometry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A | 80 | For | blahblah |
| 1 | 2 | BL | 15 | For | blahblah |
| 1 | 3 | P | 5 | For | blahblah |
| 2 | 1 | S | 75 | Misc. | blahblah |
| 2 | 2 | E | 25 | Misc. | blahblah |
| 2 | 3 | *na* | 0 | Misc. | blahblah |
| 3 | 1 | PA | 61 | Gra | blahblah |
| 3 | 2 | AT | 39 | Gra | blahblah |
| 3 | 3 | *na* | 0 | Gra | blahblah |
| 4 | 1 | *na* | 0 | *na* | blahblah |
| 4 | 2 | *na* | 0 | *na* | blahblah |
| 4 | 3 | *na* | 0 | *na* | blahblah |

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below code

```r
sf %>% group_by(UID) %>% 
  mutate(zone1=ifelse(any(SPECIES %in% c('A','AT')), 'Misc.', NA),
    zone2=ifelse(all(SPECIES %in% c('na')), 'na', NA),
    zone3=ifelse(any(SPECIES %in% c('A','AT') & PERCENT>=80), 'For',NA),
    zone4=ifelse(any(SPECIES %in% c('A','AT') & PERCENT<80), 'Gra',NA),
    zone=ifelse(is.na(coalesce(zone3,zone4,zone2,zone1)),'Misc.',coalesce(zone3,zone4,zone2,zone1))) %>% 
  select(-c(zone1:zone4))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
# A tibble: 12 × 6
# Groups:   UID [4]
     UID ORDER SPECIES PERCENT geometry zone 
   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>     <dbl> <chr>    <chr>
 1     1     1 A            80 blahblah For  
 2     1     2 BL           15 blahblah For  
 3     1     3 P             5 blahblah For  
 4     2     1 S            75 blahblah Misc.
 5     2     2 E            25 blahblah Misc.
 6     2     3 na            0 blahblah Misc.
 7     3     1 PA           61 blahblah Gra  
 8     3     2 AT           39 blahblah Gra  
 9     3     3 na            0 blahblah Gra  
10     4     1 na            0 blahblah na   
11     4     2 na            0 blahblah na   
12     4     3 na            0 blahblah na
```

Comment: Thank you, this is really good guidance for a much larger and more complicated dataset

Comment: thank you, could you please consider it as an answer